# Getting error while starting a linux vm in google cloud

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, vps, quota

its a new account. configured all the billing issues and activated the account.
was trying to start a asia-south1(mumbai) server

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J7t5.png)

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmMLJ.png)

[vm instance limit is 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcPvO.png)

[global cpus limit is 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM3eh.png)

its my first vps from gcp so i dont get it why the limit is popping up.

Comment: Your CPU quota (limit) for that region is 0. This means you cannot launch VM in that region. Request a quota increase: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the thing is in asia-south1 region that doesn't allow to launch of any CPU. Maybe there is some restriction. Try to launch your resources in another region. If everything is ok then the region is your root cause.
You aren't the one who faced this issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind that error is that you don't have CPU quota for that region `asia-south1`, the CPU limit screenshot that you shared shows the global CPU limit (for all regions), you should filter by desired region like you did in the VM instance limit screenshot. You can use this metrics to filter it:

> Service: Compute Engine API
>
> Name: CPUs
>
> Quota Metric: compute.googleapis.com/cpus
>
> Limit Name: CPUS-per-project-zone/CPUS-per-project-region

You have an explanation in the quotas [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#regional_and_global_quotas)

> VM quotas are managed at the regional level. VM instance, instance group, CPU, and disk quotas can be consumed by any VM in the region, regardless of zone. For example, CPU quota is a regional quota, so there is a different limit and usage count for each region. To launch an n2-standard-16 instance in any zone in the us-central1 region, you need enough quota for at least 16 CPUs in us-central1.

You can try to create the same resource in another region. If you need the VM created in `asia-south1` and the issue persists, you will need to [request a quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) for that service.